# Parsing expressions in PL/SQL - optimization

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, query-optimization

The context:
I'm trying to evaluate some code that I have within PL/SQL and update columns with it.
Example expressions:

```
(5+1)  
(5+1)*3 / (case when 'some_text' = 'some_text' then 1 else 2 end)
```

The expressions are basically anything that would work when put in between

```
SELECT ... FROM dual;
```

---

Obvious simple answer is an EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, and it works:

```
p_code := '(5+1)'
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE some_table SET some_col = ' || p_code ||;
```

value of some_col column will be set to evaluation of 5+1, so 6. That's what I want.

---

The problem arises with optimization.
I have many rows to update like this and I can't figure a way other than looping through my records 1 by 1, aka slow by slow.
I can't get FORALL to work- it only works with bind variables.
Do you have any other ideas how to approach this issue?

Comment: with out concrete sample data, it is hard to gurss what you exactly want to do

Comment: There is no need for concrete data I believe, the crux of the problem is: how to evaluate such expression in pl/sql OR bulk.   
I managed to make it faster by doing row by row inserts to tmp table and then running an update but it's still slow.

Comment: You just need to add a WHERE clause to your EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement to limit it to the rows you want to update

Comment: This isn't a good idea. Reserve EXECUTE IMMEDIATE for situations where referenced objects or join clauses may dynamically differ. Use normal SQL for everything else. Assign your expression results to a variable and use that variable in your SQL, without trying to build dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Lol you want some dynamic in your query, that we can not understand, without data please read up on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question as it seems pretty clear to me. Not every question needs a perfectly reproducible test case.

Answer (score 0):

A small amount of batching can go a long way for improving performance. Even if you have to "hard-code" your batching, and the code looks stupid, you can still significantly improve performance.

Batching improves performance by reducing the overhead of things like context switching, parsing, privilege checks, network traffic, etc. A batch size of just 2 removes 50% of the overhead, as demonstrated by the below code. The first PL/SQL block evaluates 1000 expressions one at a time, in 0.48 seconds.  The second PL/SQL block evaluates 1000 expressions two at a time, in 0.23 seconds.

```
--One expression at a time. Run times in seconds: 0.432, 0.523, 0.482
declare
    v_count number;
    v_expression varchar2(100);
begin
    --1000 expressions: 
    for i in 1 .. 1000 loop
        v_expression := '4 + ' ||i;
        execute immediate 'select ' || v_expression || ' from dual' into v_count;
    end loop;
end;
/

--Two expressions at a time: Run times in seconds: 0.241, 0.231, 0.230
declare
    v_count1 number;
    v_count2 number;
    v_expression1 varchar2(100);
    v_expression2 varchar2(100);
begin
    for i in 1 .. 500 loop
        v_expression1 := '4 + ' ||i;
        v_expression2 := '4 + ' ||i;
        execute immediate 'select ' || v_expression1 || ', ' || v_expression2 || ' from dual'
        into v_count1, v_count2;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

There's only so much overhead to remove, and it happens in a 1/N harmonic progression, so you don't need a very large batch size to gain near-optimal efficiency. Running ten expressions at a time removes 90%, 100 expressions at a time removes 99%, etc. Pick some smallish number like 10, apologize to your coworkers for the ugly code, deal with the annoying edge cases when the number of expressions is not a multiple of 10, and call it a day.